# Number Pyramid Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

I was searching around the internet trying to find the algorithm of the following pyramid:

```
                           1
                        2  3  2
                     3  4  5  4  3
                  4  5  6  7  6  5   4
               5  6  7  8  9  8   7  6  5   
            6  7  8  9  10 11 10  9  8  7  6
          7 8  9  10 11 12 13 12 11 10  9  8 7
       8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 14 13 12 11 10 9  8
    9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10
```

I wasn't able to find the algorithm, my question is: Does anyone know the algorithm and/or name for this type of pyramid?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm sorry if anything in the post is wrong in some way, new posting here.

Comment: The most important aspect of a question is showing what you tried! What did you try?

Comment: Even though you didn't find the algorithm, this is an easy **and** interesting exercice.

Comment: Homework :p... It's just a problem I have to solve, but can't find the name to this pyramid :/.

Comment: You should be find the pattern in the length of the rows and the numbers (and their orders!) in them. It is really not a hard task afterwards to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution .... but you should not be lazy, this isn't so hard :)

It is written in Java ....
What you see in the System.out.print() is "Ternary operator". You need to check if it is two digit number, to reduce the number of empty spaces.

```
public static void Pyramid(int rows) {
    int r = 1; // r is current row
    int emptySpaces = rows;

    while(r <= rows) {
        //print the empty spaces (3 empty spaces in one iteration)
        for(int i = 1; i < emptySpaces; i++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        //print the numbers to the middle including the middle number
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            System.out.print((r+i)/10 == 0 ? (r+i + "  ") : (r+i + " "));
        }            
        //print the numbers from the middle to the end
        for(int i = r-2; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print((r+i)/10 == 0 ? (r+i + "  ") : (r+i + " "));
        }
        //print new line, reduce empty spaces
        System.out.println("");
        emptySpaces--;
        r++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to know how all of this works because I need to transfer all of this to assembly. Thanks again.